# Approach to Primary Key on Related Tables to Save Storage Space

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I have a question regarding primary keys in Relational Databases.  Let's assume that I have the following tables:

Box

- id
- box_name

BoxItems

- id
- item_name
- belongs_to_box_id (foreign key)

Let's also assume that I intend to store millions of items per day. I would probably use `bigint` or a `guid` for the BoxItems.Id.

What I was thinking, and I need your advice on that, is instead of Bigint Id for the BoxItems, use a sequencial `TinyInt` number and what identified each item is the combination of the belongs_to_box_id plus the tinyint row (e.g. item_numner).

So now instead of the above we get:

BoxItems

- belongs_to_box_id
- item_sequence_number [TINYINT]
- item_name

Example:

```
Items.Insert(1,1, "my item 1");
Items.Insert(1,2, "my item 2");
```

So instead of using bigint or GUID for that matter, I can use tinyint and save a lot of disk space.

I want to know what the cons and pros of such approach. I am developing my app using MySQL and ASP.NET 4.5

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do with the data.  The physical data structure is driven by application requirements.  After all, if you want to save lots of space, don't store anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you think about it, there's really not much difference between the "box/contents" problem and the "order/line item" problem.

```
create table boxes (
  box_id integer primary key,
  box_name varchar(35) not null
);

create table boxed_items (
  box_id integer not null references boxes (box_id),
  box_item_num tinyint not null,
  item_name varchar(35) not null
);
```

For MySQL, you'd probably use unsigned integer and unsigned tinyint. There's no compelling reason for a database to avoid negative numbers, but developers should lean on the [Principle of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Make sure 256 values are enough. Getting that wrong can be expensive to correct in a table that gets millions of rows each day.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a simple test for both approaches and compare performance, disk space and ease of implementation and make a judgement call. Both of your suggestions are reasonable and I doubt there will be much of a difference in performance but the best way to find out is to just try it out and then you will know for sure.

Comment: I removed the signature from your answer, they should not be included in answers but feel free to place it on your profile page.